# Carregamento de MemoryStream C#

Tags: c#

Como faço para carregar um documento com mais de 4069 kb.

Exemplo: tenho um documento de 14.000 kb para carregar na `MemoryStream` que não carrega pois está dando uma exceção de memória! Como posso fazer para carregar esse arquivo?

Trecho do código:

```
public ElementImage(string imageBase64, Size size, Point position, bool stretch)
    : base()
{
    this.imgBase64 = imageBase64;
    this.Size = size;
    this.Position = position;
    this.Stretch = stretch;

    byte[] imageData = Convert.FromBase64String(imageBase64);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageData))
    {
        if (stretch)
            this.img = Image.FromStream(ms);
        else
        {
            Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(Image.FromStream(ms));
            Bitmap bmpCrop = bmpImage.Clone(new Rectangle(this.Position.X, this.Position.Y, (int)this.Size.Width, (int)this.Size.Height), bmpImage.PixelFormat);
            this.img = (Image)(bmpCrop);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: o carregamento é feito como? poderia colocar um trecho de código onde isso se dá? Qual seu objetivo fazendo tal carregamento, deseja analisar o arquivo carregado ou usar suas infos?

Comment: Eu carrego um xml em uma MemoryStream , que cria um documento xml de visualização para impressão. Só que ele só carrega até 4069 kb! e preciso carregar em torno de 2k de paginas para mais.

Comment: é viavel dividir esse xml e carrega-lo por partes nesse template de vizualização para impressão?

Comment: Coloca trechos de código na pergunta para ajudar a exemplificar a forma que está fazendo o carregamento do arquivo

Comment: Editei o post com uma parte do código.

Comment: Qual é a exata mensagem que vc está recebendo sobre "exceção de memória?"?

Comment: A exceção acontece na bmpCrop, certo? Experimente trocar os dois primeiros parâmetros por 0, se não for isso que está recebendo, porque pode ser que esteja fora do escopo os valores de position. E também, ql é o valor de pixelFormat?